# How to determine if a web page, stream ouput is via ssr or websocket?

Tags: javascript

I'm a JS newbie, I've been working on LLM applications lately, and I've seen that Openai uses SSR. Still, I'd like to analyze the interface and format of a specific request via F12 and use it as a reference for my LLM application interface design.

How should I analyze interfaces like streaming output?

I'm looking at the interface via F12, but I can't see the specific streaming outputs